Trying to crop PointClouds with face Landmarks from mediapipe
I'm using mediapipe and open3d to crop the face part of the point cloud, I take a screen shot in open3d and use mediapipe to estimate the facelandmarks, then i create a polygon volume from those landmark points and crop the point cloud of the body, but i don't now why it does not work as it should.
Code, pcd is the point cloud of the face landmaks and pcd[0] the body point cloud:
 vol = o3d.visualization.SelectionPolygonVolume()

    vol.orthogonal_axis = "Y"
    vol.axis_max = maxy1
    vol.axis_min = miny1

    vol.bounding_polygon = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(pcd.points)

    cropped_pcd = vol.crop_point_cloud(pcds[0])


    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd, cropped_pcd, sphere, bounding_box1, bounding_box0], mesh_show_back_face=True)
    o3d.io.write_point_cloud(("Set2/Fase2/"+ faccia +"/face_%d.ply" % i), cropped_pcd)




Can you make a reproducible example? The mediapipe code is missing. You also didnt clarify what the issue is? Is it part of face getting cropped?

Sorry for the missing part, the problem is that some face parts that should't be crop are missing. I need to crop the body point cloud using a point cloud that you can see in the second image. This is the part in the code where i use the face landmarks point to create the raw point cloud of the face:                                                  pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()         pcd.points.extend(points)

Try to create convex hull from the points and then use this convex hull to crop the pointcloud.

Can you please write me the code line to do that, i created the hull but i can't find how to use that to crop.

Using the convex hull point the result is worse.

hull, pcd_points = pcd.compute_convex_hull(joggle_inputs=True) - Here, hull is a TriangleMesh. Try visualizing the hull. As per my speculation, some of the face points should be extruding out of the hull. If the speculation is true,scaling the hull by a small fraction should do the job. For example: hull.scale(1.1, center=hull.get_center())

Thanks for responding, how do i use the hull/TriangleMesh to crop the face point cloud.

Since convex hull is convex, its watertight. https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/distance_queries.html. Check if signed distance is less than 0 (inside a mesh). If you dont need this accurate, you can replace convex hull with OBB (oriented bounding box). Pointcloud has a crop method which works with obb - https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.geometry.PointCloud.crop

The problem is that i need to made an accurate crop.
